# How to get the value of an input[type="number"]

Tags: javascript

```
<select id="height" name="" id="">
   <option value="FEET">FEET</option>
   <option value="INCHES">INCHES</option>
</select>
    <input id="heightNum" type="number">
```

When I click btn, I want the number inside heightNum to display. However I either get a blank line in the console or "0". So if I type say 123 in the input, I still get "0" or a blank line. Thanks in advance.

```
var height = document.getElementById('height').value.toLowerCase();
var heightNum =  document.getElementById('heightNum').value;

function calcBmi () {
if (height=="feet") {
console.log(heightNum);
 }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', calcBmi);
```

Comment: you assign values to `height` and `heightNum` outside of the event handler; that means that they will always retain whatever value the input had when those variables were first assigned. To have your event handler perform its calculation on the _current_ value of the inputs, simply declare your variables in the handler itself

Comment: Ok thanks @Hamms ....I just did that however the heightNum is still displayed as a string.  Is this normal? I put 3 in the input box then added 3 in javascript but it logged "33" to the console instead of 6.

Comment: Yes, that's expected; input `.value` is always a string

Answer (score 3):

You're getting confused about when values are assigned to variables.

`heightNum` is a variable that gets initialized ONCE when the page first loads. This value will not automatically update as the `heightNum` element changes.

Simply fetch the control values inside `calcBmi`. Then you know you will be fetching the values as they are when the `click` event fires.

```
function calcBmi () {
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value.toLowerCase();
    var heightNum =  document.getElementById('heightNum').value;
    if (height=="feet") {
        console.log(heightNum);
     }
   }

btn.addEventListener('click', calcBmi);
```